# React native App get stuck at launch screen after adding firebase crashlytics?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I am working on React native App which is working fine. But when i import firebase crashlytics it stuck at launch screen if i remove it again app work fine?

As I am new to react i am not able to get root cause for this issue?

i am trying to import crashlytics in index.js as bellow

```
    //import '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics'
    or 
    //import {crashlytics} from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';
    or
    import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';
```

Please suggest root cause, solution or way to fix this issue.
Please let me know if more info needed to understand this issue.

Thank you for helping.

app.js

```
import React from "react"
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Root } from "native-base"
import UserInactivity from 'react-native-user-inactivity';

import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import AppNavigatorRoot, { AppNavigationUtils } from "src/routers/navigations";
import store from 'src/store/';
import Loading from 'src/components/loading';
import Dialog from 'src/components/dialog';
import OAuthAPI from 'src/api/oauth';
import * as CoreConfig from 'src/config/config';
import HocErrorCatch from 'src/common/error';
```

index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
// import {name as appName} from './app.json';
//import '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics'

//import {  } from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';
//import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';



AppRegistry.registerComponent("xyz", () => App);
```

error log

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in your metro bundler?

Comment: This might be a splash screen issue if you are using splash screen, you might try this library to hide/show splash screen https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

Comment: @wahid_abdul there is not error in metro bundler but when i try to debug it says "Could not debug. Unable to find plist file to configure debugging"

Comment: @shubhamjha thanks..but i can see this is happening only when  i import crashlytics

Comment: have you tried after deleting node modules and deleting the cache using `npm start --reset-cache` ?

Comment: @shubhamjha yes i tried this too

Comment: can you show the code of app.js and index.js ?

Comment: @shubhamjha added code as requested

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The way you are trying to import a package is not correct. You should be importing it like this</strike>

`import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';`

Then you can use `crashlytics`  and log any event.

Here is the documentation [link](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage#crash-attributes). Hope this will solve the issue.

After OP edited the question, this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: thanks for help..i tried this also but still getting same error..tried removing and reinstalling the app too

Comment: Have you configured react-native-firebase correctly?

Comment: yes i am able to see firebase analytics and activities correctly in firebase console

Answer (score 0):

I don't think purely importing Crashlytics will have your app stuck at splash screen. I think you must have made some crashlytics call at splash screen, since you mentioned removing it will have the app work again.

I suppose you are using RNFirebase v6. Hence consider to doing the following:

```
import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';

componentDidMount(){
crashlytics().log('App started.');
}
```

The sample code above should work with no issue. For more info, you may [refer here](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage#crash-attributes). Consider to check the version of your `react-native-firebase/crashlytics` at `package.json` as well. I have `"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^8.1.2",` in my project.

Comment: even i remove crashlytics log.. getting same

Comment: It's confusing to us when you mentioned "But when i import firebase crashlytics it stuck at launch screen **if i remove it again app work fine**?" consider make correction to your question

Comment: Also you yon't need to `import crashlytics` at `index.js`. You can import and use that at `app.js`. And like what you mention now, if you remove crashlytics your app still stuck, try remove those import one by one to find out which is the on causing the issue.

Comment: sorry for confusing statement.. i mean if i remove crashlytics.log statement but keep import statement as it is..its still getting stuck and launch screen

Comment: i tried importing it only in app.js but still getting same error.. actually i tried in 2 diff. mac machine but its same for both

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this point TommyLeong made

> I don't think purely importing Crashlytics will have your app stuck at
> splash screen

for quick fix
install `react-native-splash-screen` 
use this code inside `App.js`, it should solve the issue

```
     import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
    
    
    // inside useEffect or componentDidMount whichever you prefer
    componentDidMount() {
            // do stuff while splash screen is shown
            // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen
            SplashScreen.hide();
    }
```