# how to know compatible firebase version for react native 0.60?

Tags: react-native

I am working on react native project with version as below

```
"react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.3",
```

i want to know compatible version of firebase for above react native version.

is there any way to find it?
and how to install particular firebase version for react native project?

Thanks for help. I am new to react native please let me know if i am misunderstanding anything

Answer (score 0):

The latest one is `V6` wich works pretty well on react-native 0.60+.
The [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/migrating-to-v6) says:

> This is a reference for upgrading from React Native Firebase v5.x.x to v6.x.x. Even though there is a lot to cover, each module generally follows similar steps to migrate.
>
> We highly recommend your project is using React Native 0.60+ before
> upgrading to take advantage of new features to make the migration
> process much simpler.

So, as expected, the latest one, it's the better one. (If you're using one of the latest versions)

Comment: thanks for info..currently i am using latest version of firebase ..but facing this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700007/react-native-app-get-stuck-at-launch-screen-after-adding-firebase-crashlytics

Comment: So, a thing you can do, is run adb logcat on your terminal, with `adb logcat` or `adb shell -x logcat` depending on your adb version. then you save the logs to a file (append ` > file.txt` if you're on linux) then, search on the logs for the error (search "firebase", so you can get the error code easy)